# How do I prove that there is a non-zero vector in the intersection?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

**The problem is:**

Let U and V be two subspaces of $R^n$. Show that if 
$$\dim(U) + \dim(V) > n$$
then there must be a non-zero vector in their intersection, i.e. $U \cap V \neq \{0\}$

---

So I know that if I take the example of $R^2$, I can let $U$ be a line in $R^2$ and $V$ be a subspace that spans all of $R^2$. It's clear that the line U is the intersection...

But how do I formally mathematically prove this in the $R^n$ case?

Comment: Do you know, or can you prove, that $\;\dim(U+V)=\dim U+\dim V-\dim(U\cap V)\;$ ? This is all you need...

Comment: If $U\cap V=\{0\}$, what can you say about $\dim(U+V)$?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, this is a direct result of the theorem relating the dimensions of the direct sum and intersection of two subspaces.  There are lots of different ways to talk about linear algebra, so here's a proof by contraposition.

Assume $U\cap V=\{0\}$.  Choose $B$ to be a basis of $U$ and $B'$ to be a basis of $V$.  Since $U\cap V=\{0\}$, $B\cup B'$ is a linearly independent set of $\dim U+\dim V$ vectors.  But those are all vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, which obviously has dimension $n$.  Therefore, $\dim U+\dim V\leq n$.